# Grep based on first 12 characters of a line, but output entire line

Tags: regex, search, grep

I have a file (patterns.txt) that contains a new-line separated list of patterns such as:

```
AAAA........
....CCCC....
........YYYY
ATCC
```

The file that i'm searching (table.txt) contains looks like this (size is 120gb):

```
ZZZZAAAAGTGT    0   1   12
AAAAGTGTAAYY    0   9   1
GGGGTTTTCCCC    1   0   0
HHHHHHHHYYYY    1   8   0
AAATCCCHHHHH    0   0   1
```

I am using the following grep command:

```
grep -f patterns.txt table.txt
```

This would return all the lines from my example. However if i could force grep to look at just first 12 characters then fist and third lines would not be returned (this is desired).

This grep is a part of a larger program. This means that patterns must come from a file. But i can change the contents of the file if neded.

I was thinking about replacing all the dots with a character class [ACGTHY]. This would mean that the pattern **AAAA........** would become:

**AAAA[ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY][ACGTHY]**

This should provide the desired result however it seems to be quite slow. Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: I was also considering replacing dots with \S.

Comment: 120GB text file means that you should be using a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need something a little more powerful. Try using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]++; next } { for (i in a) if ($1 ~ i) print }' patterns table
```

Results:

```
AAAAGTGTAAYY    0   9   1
HHHHHHHHYYYY    1   8   0
AAATCCCHHHHH    0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify patterns.txt?

In that case adding a `^` before each line will do the trick. This will match your patterns only if they start a line.

Comment: Then the last line in table.txt would not be returned by grep

Comment: In that particular case, you can omit the start of line search when the pattern is not twelve characters long. But that being the case, I think it will be easier to simply write a script that does this for you.